# IE 7 crashes and just closes without any message

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, crash

I am experiencing a very strange problem with Internet Explorer 7. When I open my page it just closes without any error message or something. My whole code works fine in all real browsers and also IE6, IE8 and IE9. The problem is IE7 specific. It crashes both in IETester and when I just simply run it. I know it's hard to answer with no code provided, but I barely can post my whole project here and, as I said, it works fine even in IE6. So, if some of you have some info (maybe you've experienced smth like that) I'd appreciate it.

**UPDATE**

As soon as I have found the issue, I am posting HTML and CSS that cause IE7 to crash. Please, note that this is not my actual code, I've created this to experiment only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <style type="text/css">
                .event_details.interface
                {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 200px;
                    background-color: grey;
                }

                .event_details.interface button
                {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                }

                .event_details.interface button[value="save"]
                {
                    right: 25px;
                }

                .event_details.interface button[value="delete"]
                {
                    right: 70px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="event_details interface">
                <button type="button" value="save">Save</button>
                <button type="button" value="delete">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Try to isolate your problem by removing chunks of code from your program until it starts working again. Hopefully you'll end up with a piece of code that can be posted here.

Comment: `code works fine in all real browsers and also IE6, IE8 and IE9`. That made me smile. I personally have yet to encounter such a thing, but if what you're experiencing is true. That my friend is one serious JS bug. Try what Jan suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. It was CSS to cause IE7 (and only) to crash. 
I had a button element on page with 'value' attribute on it. And in CSS I had:

```
button[value="save"]
{
    right: 20px;
}
```

I changed 'value' attribute to 'name' attribute and styled it like:

```
button[name="save"]
{
    right: 20px;
}
```

Now it works. Thanks everybody for your answers.

Comment: Would you mind posting the HTML too? I tried reproducing the crash with no effect.

Comment: @Khez I updated my answer with HTML as you asked. Sorry for such a delay, I have been quite busy this week.

Answer (score 0):

Run your page thru the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/). I use it like a debugger for my HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Run your page through FireFox.  (Open up the WebDeveloper-Error Console first).

Assuming it doesn't also crash FireFox, you should see where and what the errors are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As soon a I am using Firebug, I would have already seen some errors if they were. Anyway, I checked WebDeveloper Error Console too, no errors found.